# Power Automate create folder from excel cell

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to create a folder as part of a flow, based upon an excel cell value.

[image]

The flow works if I use a cell value from the excel sheet that is a straight value such as "Folder 1", but just comes up blank when I use a cell that is a formula such as "=B2 & " RFE " & ROW(2:2)".

Is there a way to get past this? Am I right in thinking that it's not working because I'm referencing a formula and not a value?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to your flow specifically and the issue you're seeing with the way you're retrieving that value (you haven't shown it) but another way to pull data from Excel and be a lot more specific about it is to use Office Scripts.

If you've never used them before, this can help you get started.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-office-scripts-in-excel-9fbe283d-adb8-4f13-a75b-a81c6baf163a#:~:text=Getting%20started,steps%20you%20want%20to%20automate.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-office-scripts-in-excel-9fbe283d-adb8-4f13-a75b-a81c6baf163a#:%7E:text=Getting%20started,steps%20you%20want%20to%20automate.)

In relation to a script that can help you, if you create a new script called `Get Cell Value` and paste this code in ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, worksheetName: string, cellAddress: string)
{
  return workbook.getWorksheet(worksheetName).getRange(cellAddress).getText();
}
```

... you can then call it from PowerAutomate and it will give you the right answer.

[image: Excel]

You can see in my example, the first cell is a formula.  From PowerAutomate using the `Run script` action, it works as expected.

[image: Result]

You can then use the resulting value to create your folder.